# How to convert Firestore REST API response to normal json?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, json.net

I am trying to use Firestore from Unity by using REST API of it. Everything is working as expected till now.

When reading document from Firestore, it returns json in different format.
Like this.

```
{
          "name": "projects/firestore-unity-demo-87998/databases/(default)/documents/test/panara",
          "fields": {
            "health": {
              "integerValue": "1008"
            },
            "name": {
              "stringValue": "Bhavin Panara"
            },
            "birthday": {
              "timestampValue": "1992-10-08T04:40:10Z"
            },
            "alive": {
              "booleanValue": true
            },
            "floatingPointNumber": {
              "testFloat": 100.1
            }
          },
          "createTime": "2019-07-30T13:27:09.599079Z",
          "updateTime": "2019-07-31T11:41:10.637712Z"
}
```

How can I convert this kind of json to a normal json like this.

```
{
  "health":1008,
  "name":"Bhavin Panara",
  "birthday" : "1992-10-08T04:40:10Z",
  "alive":true,
  "floatingPointNumber":100.1
}
```

Comment: how are you querying the database anyway? could you provide more code, as there may be an alternative to object parsing

Comment: I am using REST API. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get

Comment: you can use firestore-parser

Comment: I am looking to do this in Unity. firestore-parser is for the web. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 4):

I used the code from [firestore-parser](https://github.com/jdbence/firestore-parser)

```js
const getFireStoreProp = (value) => {
  const props = {
    arrayValue: 1,
    bytesValue: 1,
    booleanValue: 1,
    doubleValue: 1,
    geoPointValue: 1,
    integerValue: 1,
    mapValue: 1,
    nullValue: 1,
    referenceValue: 1,
    stringValue: 1,
    timestampValue: 1,
  };
  return Object.keys(value).find(k => props[k] === 1);
};

export const fireStoreParser = (value) => {
  let newVal = value;
  // You can use this part to avoid mutating original values
  //   let newVal;
  //   if (typeof value === 'object') {
  //     newVal = { ...value };
  //   } else if (value instanceof Array) {
  //     newVal = value.slice(0);
  //   } else {
  //     newVal = value;
  //   }
  const prop = getFireStoreProp(newVal);
  if (prop === 'doubleValue' || prop === 'integerValue') {
    newVal = Number(newVal[prop]);
  } else if (prop === 'arrayValue') {
    newVal = ((newVal[prop] && newVal[prop].values) || []).map(v => fireStoreParser(v));
  } else if (prop === 'mapValue') {
    newVal = fireStoreParser((newVal[prop] && newVal[prop].fields) || {});
  } else if (prop === 'geoPointValue') {
    newVal = { latitude: 0, longitude: 0, ...newVal[prop] };
  } else if (prop) {
    newVal = newVal[prop];
  } else if (typeof newVal === 'object') {
    Object.keys(newVal).forEach((k) => { newVal[k] = fireStoreParser(newVal[k]); });
  }
  return newVal;
};
```

Comment: how about the other way around for like, updates?

Answer (score 0):

```
function toValue(field) {
  return "integerValue" in field
    ? Number(field.integerValue)
    : "doubleValue" in field
    ? Number(field.doubleValue)
    : "arrayValue" in field
    ? field.arrayValue.values.map(toValue)
    : "mapValue" in field
    ? toJSON(field.mapValue)
    : Object.entries(field)[0][1];
}

function toJSON(doc) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(doc.fields ?? {}).map(([key, field]) => [key, toValue(field)])
  );
}
```